# Erro de conexão com SMTP ao enviar email usando PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou tentando implementar envio de email com a biblioteca **[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)**, porém te me trazido os seguintes erros:

**`Edit:`** Estou testando localmente.

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu corretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou porque o host conectado não respondeu. (10060)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

**`Edit 2:`** Segue parte do **[var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php)** do objeto com mensagens relacionadas ao erro

```
 private 'language' => 
    array (size=13)
      'provide_address' => string 'You must provide at least one recipient email address.' (length=54)
      'mailer_not_supported' => string ' mailer is not supported.' (length=25)
      'execute' => string 'Could not execute: ' (length=19)
      'instantiate' => string 'Could not instantiate mail function.' (length=36)
      'authenticate' => string 'SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.' (length=35)
      'from_failed' => string 'The following From address failed: ' (length=35)
      'recipients_failed' => string 'SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: ' (length=45)
      'data_not_accepted' => string 'SMTP Error: Data not accepted.' (length=30)
      'connect_host' => string 'SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.' (length=43)
      'file_access' => string 'Could not access file: ' (length=23)
      'file_open' => string 'File Error: Could not open file: ' (length=33)
      'encoding' => string 'Unknown encoding: ' (length=18)
      'signing' => string 'Signing Error: ' (length=15)
```

Abaixo segue meu código de envio:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();

$email->IsSMTP();
$email->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // tbm já tentei tls
$email->Port = 587; // tbm já tentei 465 e tbm sem porta nenhuma
$email->SMTPDebug = 1;
$email->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";    
$email->SMTPAuth = true;
$email->Username = "meuEmailDoGmail@gmail.com";
$email->Password = "minhaSenha";
$email->From = $para;

$email->SetLanguage("en", "../biblioteca/phpmailer/language/");
$email->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$email->FromName = $nome_remetente;
$email->Subject = $assunto;
$email->IsHtml(true);
$email->AddAddress($para);
$email->Body = $msg;

if(!$email->send()){
    //return false;
    die(var_dump($email->ErrorInfo));
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: você está a testar esse código num servidor ou no seu computador?

Comment: Estou testando localmente.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver @LeoFelipe?

Comment: Para min não estava dando certo de forma alguma, ate que desabilitei o avast, Sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No fim, o problema era por conta do Servidor da empresa que estava bloqueando, de alguma maneira. O admin mecheu os pauzinhos no servidor e funcionou.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:** Aguardando retorno do OP após conversa no chat

Primeiramente a porta do gmail é `465` e não `587`

Para você usar PHP Mailer com o gmail deve fazer da seguinte forma

```
$mail= new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP utilizado
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = 'seu email';
$mail->Password = 'sua senha';
$mail->SetFrom('seu email', 'seu nome(ou qualquer coisa que quiser)');
$mail->addAddress('email do destinatario','qualquer coisa que quiser');
$mail->Subject=("Assunto");
$mail->msgHTML("Sua mensagem");
if ($mail->send()){
    $ok = true;
}else{
    $ok = false;
}
```

Esse é o código que eu uso para smtp do gmail e sempre tem funcionado...

Comment: Oi @RodrigoBorth, eu pus um comentário no código dizendo que tentei tanto com porta 587 quanto 465, das 2 formas tem trazido a mesma mensagem de erro. Também usei SMTPSecure tanto como tls quanto ssl, mesma coisa. Agora esqueci de comentar que estou testando localmente, será que há problema?

Comment: Não tem problema, você leu a parte em que mudar o `SMTPDebug = false;`? isso é muito importante para o gmail, se ele estiver ativo o gmail não vai mandar @LeoFelipe

Comment: modifiquei ficando `SMTPDebug = false;`. Mesmo assim a mensagem de erro aparece: `SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host`.

Comment: @LeoFelipe coloca debug=2 e posta a mensagem de erro, assim ela vem mais completa pra que possamos te ajudar

Comment: Cara, continua a mesma mensagem de erro. Eu dei um var_dump() no objeto. Atualizarei o post com o resultado.

Comment: @LeoFelipe você está usando o mesmo email em `$mail->SetFrom` e `$mail->Username`?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15812/discussion-between-rodrigoborth-and-leofelipe).

Comment: @RodrigoBorth veja a edição que fiz em sua resposta e corrija a linha $mail->Subject, ok ? []s!

Comment: @gpupo não entendi oque você quis dizer com `que sintaxe é essa?`

Comment: @LeoFelipe não sei como está nas outras versões, mas na minha addAddress é com letra minuscula, veja se isso não está dando problema tambem

Comment: @RodrigoBorth no seu código está $mail->Subject=("Assunto"); então quero entender ser você está atribuindo valor a Subject ou chamando um método mas esqueceu um IGUAL ali no meio. Seu código não deveria ser $mail->Subject="Assunto"; ?

Comment: @gpupo a unica diferença entre o que você escreveu e o que eu escrevi é o uso dos parenteses "( )" que em nada influenciam... nesse caso estou atribuindo um valor a um variável publica da classe ... é o mesmo caso do include ('arquivo'); ou include 'arquivo';

Answer (score 2):

Desde o final do ano passado (2014) o Google exige um mecanismo de autenticação mais seguro (XOAuth2) em vários serviços. Isto inclui o Gmail.

Pode ser este o erro que você está recebendo. Para que funcione você deve habilitar a opção "Permitir que aplicativos menos seguros acessem sua conta".

Faça login em sua conta e acesse o endereço: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Você pode obter mais informações sobre isto neste link:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

Comment: Eu tive esse problema e precisei ativar esse recurso do gmail depois disso envio normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Altere a porta para `587` e a conexão para `ssl`

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

//======================================================================
// CONFIGURAÇÕES DE ENVIO
//======================================================================
      $dispatcher       = array(
        "smtp_prefix"   => "smtp", //Apenas o prefixo, ex: smtp, caso: smtp.dominio.com.br
        "port"          => "587",
        "subject"       => "assunto_email", //Assunto do e-mail
        "from"          => "seu_email@gmail.com", //Email remetente
        "from_name"     => "seu_nome", //Nome do remetente
        "from_password" => "sua_senha", //Senha rementente
        "to"            => "email_destinario"); //Destinatario


//======================================================================
// CORPO DO EMAIL
//======================================================================

  $message = 'Essa mensagem é um email de teste, caso tenha recebido está tudo ok!';

//======================================================================
// [FIM] CORPO DO EMAIL
//======================================================================



  include_once("./phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';    // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
  $mail->Host = "{$dispatcher["smtp_prefix"]}.".substr(strstr($dispatcher["from"], '@'), 1);
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // 1 = erros e mensagens || 2 = apenas mensagens
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Port = $dispatcher["port"];
  $mail->Username = $dispatcher["from"];
  $mail->Password = $dispatcher["from_password"];

  $mail->SetFrom($dispatcher["from"], $dispatcher["from_name"]);
  $mail->Subject = $dispatcher["subject"];
  $mail->MsgHTML($message);
  $mail->AddAddress($dispatcher["to"]);
  $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $mensagemRetorno = 'Erro ao enviar e-mail: '. print($mail->ErrorInfo);
  } else {
    //Exemplo resposta usando JavaScript
    $sucesso = '<script> document.write("E-mail enviado com sucesso!"); </script>';
    echo $sucesso;
  }

?>
```

**Informativo sobre porta 587:**

> **Serviços como Gmail, Yahoo! e Hotmail serão afetados?** Haverá mudanças apenas para quem usa programas leitores de e-mail, quem usa
>   esses serviços via webmail não precisa mudar a configuração. Todos
>   estes provedores de e-mail já oferecem o serviço de submissão na porta
>   587/TCP. Fonte: [AntiSpam.BR](http://www.antispam.br/porta25/tire-suas-duvidas/)

Comment: a portal do gmail não é 465?

Comment: Ele funciona com a porta `587`, definido como padrão aqui para o Brasil: [Veja mais...](http://antispam.br/images/InfograficoPorta25.jpg) ou  [Guia Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=pt-BR)

Comment: Adicionei na resposta também, parece que nem todo mundo conhece as mudanças.

Comment: Já havia visto isso, porém, a 587 não funciona pra mim... só consigo usar o gmail com a porta 465, no restante dos provedores uso a 587 normalmente

Comment: Tente verificar se há algum programa impedindo, você pode testar a porta 587 realizando um telnet: [teste de resposta porta 587](http://pastebin.com/NkhTNBVv)

Comment: @LeoFelipe da uma olhada nesses comentarios, pode ser que te ajuda

Comment: Bem, acho que isso pode ajudar, mesmo estando falando do Gmail: no cPanel a porta 587 é utilizada para comunicações sem a camada SSL e a porta 465 é para o contrario, ou seja, creio que o mais correto seja usara a porta 465 junto com a camada SSL, já que ambas são utilizadas pelo Gmail