# Não consigo enviar email com o PHPMailer no servidor

Tags: phpmailer

```
require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->setLanguage('pt');

$from = 'emaildoservidor@servidor.com';
$fromName = 'EmailServidor';

$host       = 'servidor.one.com';
$username   = 'emaildoservidor@servidor.com';
$password   = '123456';
$port       = 587;
$secure     = false;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host         = $host;
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
$mail->Username     = $username;
$mail->Password     = $password;
$mail->Port         = $port;
$mail->Secure       = $secure;

$mail->From         = $from;
$mail->FromName     = $fromName;

$mail->addAddress('usuario@hotmail.com', 'Usuario');

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->WordWrap = 70;

$mail->Subject = 'Confirmação de Cadastro';
$mail->Body    = 'Email de teste.';
$mail->AltBody = 'Email de teste.';

$send = $mail->Send();

if($send)
    echo 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!';
else
    echo 'Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
```

Então eu fiz os testes no localhost com o Xampp e funcionou, porem quando fui testar no servidor One.com, ele não enviava a mensagem e também não mostrava nenhum erro. Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: O e-mail remetente(from) esta correto, existe no servidor?, tem servidores que tem políticas de segurança que apenas aceitam o envio de e-mail que existam, outros servidores você pode colocar qualquer e-mail no from que passa, tem que verificar também as portas de envio do servidor se não são outras.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro de conexão com SMTP ao enviar email usando PHPMailer](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25672/erro-de-conex%c3%a3o-com-smtp-ao-enviar-email-usando-phpmailer)

Comment: Verifica tambem se o seu provedor nao requere envio de smtp ssl : $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"

Comment: Mas acho que o problema e no servidor, pois quando eu uso o script no localhost ele funciona, ja no servidor ele simplismente nao retorna nada, fica carregando infinitamente.

Comment: Qual a versão do php no teu servidor @Ingi?

Comment: 5.6, desculpa a demora estava sem internet por uns dias @Guilherme Nascimento